# Base 64 string corrupt

Tags: java, eclipse

I am attempting to save a bitmap image as base64 then write the base64 to a file,  this all appears to work but when I attempt to load the output in a .net application I get an error 'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.'

The image is created from a canvas using:

```
mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(),      Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);;
```

I use to encode the base64 string: String ba1=  encodeTobase64(mBitmap);

Is it writing the base 64 to a file that is causing the error or is my method incorrect?

Comment: This isn't JavaScript -- Java and JavaScript are _completely_ different.

Comment: You need to give the code of `encodeTobase64`.

Comment: Sorry as you can see I am new to this!

Comment: So what does the file look like?  Have you examined it?

Comment: I have attempted to update my code after your prompt and now have:

                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
                
                String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray,  Base64.DEFAULT);

But I am still getting the same error!

Comment: The file is 23000 characters long so I have reproduced the the first few and the last lines:  /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBCiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAK KKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAC

Comment: Have you compared the (Base64 encoded) data you're putting into the file to the data you're reading back?

Comment: Hi sorry it has taken me some time to get back,  I have tested the Base64 before saving and the result is the same!  I grab the encoded string in eclipse log-cat and test this and stillget errors!